# Get list of enums from enum without type

Tags: c#, enums

Using reflection, I have an enum value. How can I get the list of all enums from that value without knowing the type of the `Enum`?

Here is some pseudo code:

```
List<string> enumList = Enum
    .GetValues(enumVal.GetType())
    .Cast<MyEnum>()
    .Select(v => v.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

In the code example, this would work if I knew that `enumVal` was `MyEnum`, but I don't: it could be any `Enum` (`MyEnum`, `YourEnum`, etc)

Comment: I don't think the `.Cast<MyEnum>()` is needed?

Comment: `var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum));` or `var enumNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(SomeEnum));` (same thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take

```
Enum.GetNames(enumVal.GetType())
```

to get an array of string values, add .ToList(); if you want a list.